# Copy first element in an array and replace the last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array with x amount of values.

How can I replace the last element in that array with the first? (Not switch positions but remove the last array and put the first in the last position)

Example:

Initial Array: [9, 14, 23 ,12 ,1]
Final Array: [9, 14, 23, 12, 9]

Comment: What don't you know how to do? Reference the first member, the last member, or do an assignment?

Comment: Sorry my mind was stuck in this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array[array.length-1] = array[0];
```

You don't need to know very much. For starters see [JavaScript Array Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any values for the array! Hope this helps! :)

```
// replaces the last index of an array with the first.
var replace = function(InputArray){
  //saves the first index of the array in var a
  var a = InputArray[0];
  //removes the last index of the array
  InputArray.pop;
  //places a copy of the first index in the place where the last index was
  InputArray.push(a);
  //returns the array
  return InputArray;
}
//call the function
replace([9, 14, 23 ,12 ,1]);
// result => [9, 14, 23, 12, 1, 9]

//If you want, you can log it in the console! 
console.log(replace([9, 14, 23 ,12 ,1]));
```